# Accessing Smartcards from a Web Site

Tags: asp.net, ssl-certificate, smartcard

A number of Countries have implemented electronic id cards, that their citizens can use to securely access online facilities like banking.

I am interested in learning how to support these cards, but tracking down documentation on how to do this from an IIS hosted website is a real PITA: In MSDN for example the bulk of the smartcard documentation covers the end to end scenario of linking smart cards to domain logins in a corporate environment.

I am just trying to authenticate the holder of - for example, a Spanish [DNI-e](http://www.dnielectronico.es/) card and perform an OSCP validation of the card via http://ocsp.dnie.es/

Now, its seems that, rather than explicitly detecting the smart card insertion, I need to create a login page on the server with SSL client authentication forced - but how do I configure one request to require ssl client authentication and to pick the correct client certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, configure your server to require client certificate authentication. You will receive the client authenticator details in the headers.

You can force to only accept specific certificates by configuring the public root certificate of those client certificates on the server and removing all others that you are not interested in. In the authentication request going from your server to the browser, only the root certificates are listed that are trusted on your server system. The client browser will only offer client certificates that are somehow related to that root.

Comment: This is the answer that I definitely did not want: There seems no way to tell IIS (<=v7.5 at least) to only accept certain certificates. This makes for a less than ideal user experience imo as users can easilly accidentally choose the wrong certificate, and browsers seem to agressivly cache the results of a ssl client cert request so subsequent requests will just continue to use the wrong cert.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion about forcing the desired certificates by supplying the root for those certificates in your trusted root and removing the rest? Or is that not suitable for your situation?

Comment: That solution does work, but I'd have prefered a finer grain of control. Adding certs to the systems trusted root means that now *Ever* application on the webserver trusts some otherwise rather random identity provider.

Answer (score 0):

In an Microsoft environment you would configure your IIS to require SSL on your login page. Additionally, require SSL client authentication using a certificate.